# Filtering column strings that contain substring

Tags: talend

I am working on an if else in the Tmap, and one of the conditions is if a column contains a substring.

I am unsure exactly how to go about this being fairly new to talend.

This is the current syntax that I am using.

```
row16.Location.contains("clos")?"Pending":""
```

I have not been able to find any good examples of the correct way to go about this, other than the one above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talend uses Java as an underlying language, so you need to use the ternary operator of Java:

```
row16.Location.contains("clos") ? "Pending" : ""
```

But make sure you first check `row16.Location` for null, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` if Location is null :

```
row16.Location != null && row16.Location.contains("clos") ? "Pending" : ""
```

Comment: Filtering the null values was the issue. Talend was supressing the error I was getting but this works. Thanks!